# Form values lost when returning to page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I've a problem.

I'm building a website with multiple pages.
In a page there is a form (with some AngularJS in it) when the user clicks the submit button, a second page appears where it confirms the form submission.
If there was any error, it will show a message with the error message with a button that goes back (`javascript:history.go(-1)`).
When the user clicks this back button, the form page is presented again but with all fields blanked (the page seems completely reloaded...). Anyway with other forms without AngularJS this mechanisms work fine...
What's wrong?

Thanks! :-)

PS: Anyway, the form page has checks that disable the submit button if there is any error, though I don't understand why the page reloads when the user returns to it via the back button while with other forms it doesn't happen...

Comment: Its not a good idea to rely on history, You can save form details in cookies

Comment: It's not safe to save form details in cookies. Either use Session Cookies or save to a database.

Answer (score 0):

If both the pages belong to same app (under the same app.js) then you can store the values of form in **$rootScope** variable instead of $scope.

Also to navigate, you can use **$location.Path**

Comment: Can I use $rootScope even if the pages are different (no Single Page App but a different HTTP request), but with the same app.js?

Comment: Yes.
If You see the scope of a variable,
$scope is available only for that controller, for that HTML page, but $rootScope is at app level, so unless app.js is called again, value will be persisted.
The main purpose for having $rootScope is to share data between controllers for same app.